# Spark throws : "expression is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function..."

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to execute this with pyspark:

```
query = "SELECT       *\
         FROM         transaction\
         INNER JOIN   factures\
         ON           transaction.t_num = factures.f_trx\
         WHERE        transaction.t_num != ''\
         GROUP BY     transaction.t_num"

result = sqlContext.sql(query)
```

Spark gives an error :

> u"expression `transaction.t_aut` is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;

Comment: Using `select *` with aggregation is just broken.  Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying that there is column named `transaction.t_aut` that you have projected in your select statement when you used `select *` that is not being used in your `group by`.

Solution is to either replace `select *` with the columns that are in your `group by` in your case `transaction.t_num` or add `transaction.t_aut` to your `group by`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add list of columns in group by statement. As you are selecting all columns in select statement.